# PyGTK - CellRendererCombo not holding newly selected value

Tags: python, user-interface, pygtk, gtk3

I'm trying to make a simple list-storing program with one of the values (columns) in a given row able to be changed with a dropdown selection. I've gotten as far as getting the dropdown into the row, however, I'm unable to have the new value committed to the column as the active value.

Using the PyGtk tutorial at http://python-gtk-3-tutorial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/cellrenderers.html, I see that they use

```
def __init__
    renderer_combo = Gtk.CellRendererCombo()
    renderer_combo.set_property("editable", True)
    renderer_combo.set_property("model", liststore_manufacturers)
    renderer_combo.set_property("text-column", 0)
    renderer_combo.set_property("has-entry", False)
    renderer_combo.connect("edited", self.on_combo_changed)

...

def on_combo_changed(self, widget, path, text):
    self.liststore_hardware[path][1] = text
```

Having copied this code into my interpreter, and viewing a program that can successfully change the value of the ComboBox, I tried to copy their methods. This led me to create the following:

```
def __init__

    ...

    self.col_priorityrenderer = Gtk.CellRendererCombo()
    self.col_priorityrenderer.set_property("editable", True)
    self.col_priorityrenderer.set_property("model", liststore_manufacturers)
    self.col_priorityrenderer.set_property("text-column", 0)
    self.col_priorityrenderer.set_property("has-entry", False)
    self.col_priorityrenderer.connect("edited", self.on_combo_changed)

    priorityCombo = Gtk.ListStore(str)
    priorityCombo.append(["Top"])
    priorityCombo.append(["High"])
    priorityCombo.append(["Medium"])
    priorityCombo.append(["Low"])
    self.col_priority_renderer.set_property("model", priorityCombo)

def on_combo_changed(self, widget, path, text):
    model = widget.get_property("model")
    model[path][1] = text
```

With this code, I get the error:

```
IndexError: column index is out of bounds: 1
```

I've changed the 1 to 0, and I don't receive that error, but it also doesn't change the active item. I've tried for about 3 days now to wrap my head around how to get this to work correctly to no avail. Why is the Index 1 out of bounds in this scenario?